# Extending Sitecore Experience Analytics Filters

Tags: experience-analytics

I'm trying to extend the experience analytics filters component by adding new custom filters that will be used for my custom reports, my question is: How I can create a textbox field using the following class?:

```
Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.RenderingHelper
```

What I can find methods to create different controls but I can't find a method create a text field.

Following is an example of creating combo box with two buttons:

```
helper.MakeComboBox("EventTypeComboBox", controlsRow, options ?? new List<ComboBoxItem>()
                                   {
                                       new ComboBoxItem()
                                   });


helper.MakeButton("SubmitButton", controlsRow, Globals.System.Texts.Apply.Guid.ToString(), "Primary");
helper.MakeButton("ResetButton", controlsRow, Globals.System.Texts.RevertFiltersToStandard.Guid.ToString());
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Rendering text

Try using:

```
helper.MakeText(
    string controlId, string parent, string text,
    TextType textType = TextType.Text, string isVisible = "True")
```

TextType enum is defined as follows:

```
 enum TextType
  {
    Text, Label, HelpLabel, LargeLabel, Value,
    LargeValue, LargeTitle, Title, SmallTitle,  Divider
  }
```

You can play around with different types of text to create different labels/titles/etc.

### Rendering text box

*From Mohammed's comment*:

I managed to do it by the following code:

```
string str = renderingId + "EventTopic"; 
this.Html.Sitecore().AddContentToPlaceholder(controlsRow + ".Content", 
this.Html.Sitecore().Controls().Rendering(this.Html, 
    "{57F86E9A-1844-45CE-BF8A-62900AE17A92}", str, "", null)
    .ToHtmlString())
```

### Generic helper

If that doesn't fit your requirement you can always use a generic method:

```
helper.CreateRenderingAt(
        string renderindItemId, string controlId, 
        string parent, object parameters = null, 
        string datasource = "", string contentPlaceholder = ".Content")
```

The **renderindItemId** parameter is an ID of the actual rendering from the component library (from **CORE** database) that you want to be rendered.

For example, if you want to render the text using the generic method, it would look like that:

```
helper.CreateRenderingAt(Globals.Bcl.Renderings.Common.Text, 
    controlId, parent, (object) new
      {
        TextType = textType,
        Text = text,
        IsVisible = isVisible
      }, "", ".Content");
```

In that method call the **Globals.Bcl.Renderings.Common.Text** constant value is **{7717EB6C-9F90-4C58-826D-5E87722A0318}**.

### More

*You can always decompile the `Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.dll` to find  more clues on how they render different components.*

Comment: I already did that, I tried MakeText method with different enumeration, This method render a text, what I need is a textbox, none of them worked for me.

Comment: There is no overload for textbox in the helper. Try passing a textbox rendering ID to the generic method

Comment: I managed to do thing by the following code:

 string str = renderingId + "EventTopic";
  this.Html.Sitecore().AddContentToPlaceholder(controlsRow + ".Content", this.Html.Sitecore().Controls().Rendering(this.Html, "{57F86E9A-1844-45CE-BF8A-62900AE17A92}", str, "", null).ToHtmlString());

Please add this to your answer for a better formatting.